# AppDomain assembly load causes Fatal Execution Engine Error (6B3979C6) (80131506)

Tags: .net, assemblies, appdomain

We have a type caching system in place to avoid searching all plug-in assemblies for all types each time our application starts up, but when moving from .NET 1.1 to 2.0+, the Event Log records a Fatal Execution Engine Error (6B3979C6) (80131506) on the AppDomain.Load()

If and ***only*** if 
1. the AppDomain is NOT AppDomain.CurrentDomain.
2. The assembly is not in the executable's directory.

We allow users to provide their own assemblies in project-specific directories, so we can't work around 2.

I believe 1. is wanted so we can unload the AppDomain to after skimming for types.

I'm not the owner of this code, but I can ask the right questions if I haven't provided enough information.

This code causes the uncatchable error:

```
    private static void AddAssembly( System.AppDomain appDom, Manifest manifest, string filenameWithoutExtension )
    {
        try
        {
            // Test that the assembly can be loaded...
            System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(filenameWithoutExtension);

            System.Reflection.Assembly assem = appDom.Load( filenameWithoutExtension );
            ArrayList attributes = new ArrayList();
            //  System.Reflection.Assembly assem = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path+"\\"+file.Name);
            object[] attribs = assem.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(PlugInAttribute), false );
            if ( attribs.Length > 0 )
            {
                attribs = assem.GetCustomAttributes( false );
                foreach ( Attribute attr in attribs )
                {
                    object[] attrAttrs = attr.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PlugInAttribute), false );
                    if ( attrAttrs.Length > 0 ) 
                    {
                        attributes.Add(attr.GetType().ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( attribs.Length > 0 || attributes.Count > 0 )
            {
                Assembly assy = new Assembly( manifest );
                manifest.Assemblies.Add(assy);
                assy.Name = filenameWithoutExtension;
                assy.Version = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName( System.IO.Path.Combine( manifest.Path, filenameWithoutExtension + ".dll") ).Version.ToString();
                assy.Attributes = (ArrayList)attributes.Clone();
                System.Type[] types = assem.GetTypes();
                foreach (System.Type type in types )
                    if ( !type.IsNestedPrivate && !type.IsNestedPublic
                        && !type.IsNestedAssembly  )
                        assy.AddType( type );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "Manifest.AddAssembly Exception: " + ex.Message );

            Manager.WriteException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a third-party licensing library which injected buggy code into the process.